# webdev npm not upload video on nextcloude server

Tags: node.js, nextcloud

[Here is the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lM4lk.png)

i want to try fetch and upload videos on nextcloude server through webdev npm. In that i fetch video properly but getting cors error while getting video so i tried to upload video on server but that time i get 409 conflict error.

here is my code which i tried.

```
    const client = createClient(
      "https://nextcloud.virtuell-trening.no/remote.php/webdav",
      {
          username: "*********",
          password: "*************",

      }
    );
    // const uploadLink = client.getFileUploadLink("C:/jatin/rejoicehub/godtrening-dev/uploads/videos/test.mp4");
    await client.putFileContents("/Uploads", req.files, { onUploadProgress: progress => {
      console.log(`Uploaded ${progress.loaded} bytes of ${progress.total}`);
    } });
```